# Что эффективней 2 ядра или 2 процессора?

Tags: сервер

Если сравнить системы с двумя процессорами, скажем Zeon DP 3Ггц и двух ядерный intel Dual-Core c такой же частотой, то какая система будет производительней!? Вопрос собственно возник из за того, что сейчас можно купить относительно не дорого б.у. сервер, с двумя процами, да ещё там есть всякие серверные приблуды, сервак соответственно серьёзной сборки (к примеру USA) Для чего нужен мне конкретно !? - будет висеть в сети софтина выполняя некоторую мат. обработку данных. Кто вообще сталкивался с б.у. серваками, у кого есть опыт расскажите может есть подводные камни? Сервак думал брать стоечный 1U HP DL360 g4

Comment: Староват сервер, будут проблемы с поддержкой.  Посмотрите на более современные с многоядерными Xeon. 

В Вашем же случае, без учета расширения системы, двух ядерный intel Dual-Core мне видится более предпочтительным.

Comment: Ядро это процессор. Они собраны в один корпус. Вопрос бессмысленный.

Comment: Нет, не бессмысленный. Разница может быть на самом деле большой. Сам факт разнесения ядер и разделения их в отдельные процессоры существенно может повлиять на эффективность работы с общей памятью.

Comment: Наоборот. Чем длиннее токоведущая линия, тем больше задержка распространения сигнала, больше реактивное сопротивление линии и соответственно медленнее протекают переходные процессы в этой линии(учите матчасть по линиям с распределенными параметрами). Процессорная шина материальна и к ней аналогичные законы физики применимы. Посему и стараются как можно более короткими их делать, интегрируя всё в один кристалл.

Comment: Это случаем не гугловские серваки? :)

Comment: @rejie Переведите свой вопрос в практическую плоскость - цена, требования к задаче. Вам ведь нужен ответ на этот вопрос, а точнее брать или нет DL360 .

А то здесь пошло теоретизирование по поводу реализации SMP архитектур.

Comment: Ну так вот.. вы сами же говорите, что есть разница. Стало быть, вопрос-то не бессмысленный совсем. Даже если ответ вам кажется очевидным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, не Zeon, а Xeon. Хотя по-русски читается вроде как "зион".
Во-вторых, два ядра или два процессора - без разницы. Отличие будет лишь в геометрии =) Ну, и плюс двухядрёный процессор может иметь разделяемые L2/L3 - см. спецификации. У двухпроцессорной системы у процов общая только RAM.
Касательно вопроса стоит ли брать DL360 G4 - у меня лично аллергия на NetBurst архитектуру. Если б там стоял внутри оптерончик или Xeon'истый Core/Core2, то брал именно их.

Comment: Стоимость этого сервака 350$ это хорошая цена!?